# Why my train perditions using LSTM are all less than one and not accurate?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I am new to Deep learning and trying to develop LSTM for COVID-19 time series prediction based on the number of confirmed cases.

Here is my dataset:

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lon1l.png)

I tried the below parameters. However, I got all results less than one.
Can you please help me?

```
X_train1, y_train1 = X1[:500], y1[:500] 
X_val1, y_val1 = X1[500:550], y1[500:550]
X_test1, y_test1 = X1[550:], y1[550:]
X_train1.shape, y_train1.shape, X_val1.shape, y_val1.shape, 
X_test1.shape, y_test1.shape
```

> ((500, 5, 1), (500,), (50, 5, 1), (50,), (218, 5, 1), (218,))

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(InputLayer((5, 1)))
model1.add(LSTM(64))
model1.add(Dense(8, 'relu'))
model1.add(Dense(1, 'linear'))

cp1 = ModelCheckpoint('model1/', save_best_only=True)
model1.compile(loss=MeanSquaredError(), optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=[RootMeanSquaredError()])

model1.fit(X_train1, y_train1, validation_data=(X_val1, y_val1), epochs=10, callbacks=[cp1])
```

please check this picture for the results sample:
[results sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Gj8f.png)

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if you could share more of your code. My hunch is that you are normalizing data during training, so the model's predictions are normalized as well. De-normalizing them may give you your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Reshape your input training, validation and testing data to to be 3D [samples, timesteps, features]:

```
X_train1 = X_train1.reshape((X_train1.shape[0], 1, X_train1.shape[1]))
X_val1 = X_val1.reshape((X_val1.shape[0], 1, X_val1.shape[1]))
X_test1 = X_test1.reshape((X_test1.shape[0], 1, X_test1.shape[1]))
X_train1.shape, y_train1.shape, X_val1.shape, y_val1.shape, 
X_test1.shape, y_test1.shape
# Output (500, 1, 5), (500,), (50, 1, 5), (50,), (218, 1, 5), (218,)
```

Comment: actually, i am using 5 as timesteps and 1 feature. here are the shapes I got  :
((60000, 5, 1), (60000,), (5000, 5, 1), (5000,), (5086, 5, 1), (5086,))

Comment: Aren't you using 5 features to predict the COVID cases?